# Connect to AWS EC2 from AWS Beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am interesting how to connect to MySQL which runs on EC2 instance from application deployed on AWS Beanstalk.

Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Curious why aren't you using the RDS instance instead of EC2? This document explains the step, the process should be pretty much similar as long as your mysql server is up and running:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html